# Failed to load PDF document in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

When I first tested this code it seemed to work just fine, but now I am getting a bug.

Failed to load PDF document

I upload a pdf via my admin function, it goes into a database, and then I have an action in my controller that allows a person to download that pdf when it is clicked on.

However, it doesn't seem to work all the time.  I also haven't been able to really identify what is causing it to break.  If the file size is over 78 kb it seems that Chrome can't open the document while Firefox/Edge can.  If the file is under 75 kb Chrome/IE opens it just fine. I am unsure of why this is happening.

I have included my controller below

```
public ActionResult DownloadPdf(int Id) {
    var dbTest = _testRepository.FindId(Id);
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition { FileName = dbTest.PdfName, Inline = true };
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return File(dbTest.PdfData, "application/pdf");
}
```

Here is my View

```
@if (Model.Test.HasPdf)
    {
        <a data-bind="css: { disabled: !form() }" href="@Url.Action("DownloadPdf", "Test", new { Id = Model.Test.Id })" target="_blank" id="launchBtn" class="btn btn-pdf">Download PDF Form</a>
}
```

Has anyone else ever had an error like this? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: What is your database column type and what is the .NET type of `PdfData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It had nothing to do with my download feature, it was in my HTTPPost

```
if (vm.FileData != null)
    {
        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(vm.FileData.ContentLength\\This code between the parenthesis was missing))
        {
            vm.FileData.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
            test.FileData = stream.GetBuffer();
            test.FileName = vm.FileData.FileName;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Supposing that your "dbTest" has a property with the PDF content as byte array (byte[]).

To direct download the file

```
public ActionResult DownloadPdf(int Id) {
    var dbTest = _testRepository.FindId(Id);

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", $"filename={dbTest.PdfName}");
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", dbTest.PdfData.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Response.BinaryWrite(dbTest.PdfData);
    Response.End();

    return null;
}
```

or to open the file in a new browser tab

```
public ActionResult DownloadPdf(int Id) {
    var dbTest = _testRepository.FindId(Id);
    return File(dbTest.PdfData, "application/pdf", dbTest.PdfName);
}
```

I hope this helps you